# CSS to put 2 form fields next to each other

Tags: html, css

I found a form online, and now i am trying to modify it to put the phone and email text fields next to each other. And i kind of managed to get it, but the formatting is not quote right. The fields are to small and when i try to make a them bigger to they can match the full name field so phone field goes to where the full name ends, it doesn't work. I've been searching online and everything and can't get this to work. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```css
.form-style-10 {
  width: 900px;
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 40px auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  -moz-box-shadow: :0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}

.form-style-10 .inner-wrap {
  padding: 30px;
  background: #F8F8F8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-style-10 h1 {
  background: #2A88AD;
  padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;
  margin: -30px -30px 30px -30px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  font: normal 30px 'Bitter', serif;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
  border: 1px solid #257C9E;
}

.form-style-10 h1>span {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 2px;
  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.form-style-10 label {
  display: block;
  font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #888;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-style-10 input[type="text"],
.form-style-10 input[type="date"],
.form-style-10 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-10 input[type="email"],
.form-style-10 input[type="number"],
.form-style-10 input[type="search"],
.form-style-10 input[type="time"],
.form-style-10 input[type="url"],
.form-style-10 input[type="password"],
.form-style-10 textarea,
.form-style-10 select {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
}

.form-style-10 .section {
  font: normal 20px 'Bitter', serif;
  color: #2A88AD;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-style-10 .section span {
  background: #2A88AD;
  padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border: 4px solid #fff;
  font-size: 14px;
  margin-left: -45px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: -3px;
}

.form-style-10 input[type="button"],
.form-style-10 input[type="submit"] {
  background: #2A88AD;
  padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
  font: normal 30px 'Bitter', serif;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
  border: 1px solid #257C9E;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.form-style-10 input[type="button"]:hover,
.form-style-10 input[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #2A6881;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
}

.form-style-10 .privacy-policy {
  float: right;
  width: 250px;
  font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #4D4D4D;
  margin-top: 10px;
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-10">
  <h1>Request Your Quote<span>Request your free quote today!</span></h1>
  <form>
    <div class="section"><span>1</span>Contact Information</div>
    <div class="inner-wrap" style="display:inline-block !important;">
      <label>Your Full Name<input type="text" name="field1" /></label>
      <div style="float:right !important; padding-right:50px; display:inline-block !important;"><label>Phone<input type="text" style="max-width:300px !important;" name="field1" /></label></div>
      <div style="float:left  !important; display:inline-block !important;padding-right: 300px;">
        <label>Email<input type="text" style="max-width:300px !important;" name="field1" /></label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-section">
      <input type="submit" name="Sign Up" />
      <span class="privacy-policy">
<input type="checkbox" name="field7">You agree to our Terms and Policy.
</span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Risking not providing a full solution, here's an attempt.
I made both inputs float to the left, added a width value to the inner wrap element (760px) and made both inputs 50% width.

```css
.form-style-10 {
 width: 900px;
 padding: 30px;
 margin: 40px auto;
 border-radius: 10px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px;
 box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
 -moz-box-shadow: :0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.13);
}

.form-style-10 .inner-wrap {
 padding: 30px;
 background: #F8F8F8;
 border-radius: 6px;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 width: 700px;
}

.form-style-10 h1 {
 background: #2A88AD;
 padding: 20px 30px 15px 30px;
 margin: -30px -30px 30px -30px;
 border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
 -webkit-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
 -moz-border-radius: 10px 10px 0 0;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
 font: normal 30px 'Bitter', serif;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
 border: 1px solid #257C9E;
}

.form-style-10 h1>span {
 display: block;
 margin-top: 2px;
 font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.form-style-10 label {
 display: block;
 font: 13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #888;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.form-style-10 input[type="text"],
.form-style-10 input[type="date"],
.form-style-10 input[type="datetime"],
.form-style-10 input[type="email"],
.form-style-10 input[type="number"],
.form-style-10 input[type="search"],
.form-style-10 input[type="time"],
.form-style-10 input[type="url"],
.form-style-10 input[type="password"],
.form-style-10 textarea,
.form-style-10 select {
 display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 8px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
 -moz-border-radius: 6px;
 border: 2px solid #fff;
 box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.33);
}

.form-style-10 .section {
 font: normal 20px 'Bitter', serif;
 color: #2A88AD;
 margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.form-style-10 .section span {
 background: #2A88AD;
 padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 50%;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
 -moz-border-radius: 50%;
 border: 4px solid #fff;
 font-size: 14px;
 margin-left: -45px;
 color: #fff;
 margin-top: -3px;
}

.form-style-10 input[type="button"],
.form-style-10 input[type="submit"] {
 background: #2A88AD;
 padding: 8px 20px 8px 20px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 color: #fff;
 text-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
 font: normal 30px 'Bitter', serif;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.17);
 border: 1px solid #257C9E;
 font-size: 15px;
}

.form-style-10 input[type="button"]:hover,
.form-style-10 input[type="submit"]:hover {
 background: #2A6881;
 -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
 -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
 box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.28);
}

.form-style-10 .privacy-policy {
 float: right;
 width: 250px;
 font: 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color: #4D4D4D;
 margin-top: 10px;
 text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-style-10">
    <h1>Request Your Quote<span>Request your free quote today!</span></h1>
    <form>
        <div class="section"><span>1</span>Contact Information</div>
        <div class="inner-wrap" style="display:inline-block !important;">
            <label>Your Full Name<input type="text" name="field1" /></label>
            <div style="float:left !important; display:inline-block !important; width: 50%;"><label>Phone<input type="text" style="max-width:300px !important;" name="field1" /></label></div>
            <div style="float:left  !important; display:inline-block !important; width: 50%;">
                <label>Email<input type="text" style="max-width:300px !important;" name="field1" /></label></div>
        </div>
        <div class="button-section">
            <input type="submit" name="Sign Up" />
            <span class="privacy-policy">
<input type="checkbox" name="field7">You agree to our Terms and Policy.
</span>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: awesome, thank you very much for your response, very helpful. Last question though, how come the text boxes can't get any bigger, i even tried setting them to 500px and it still stays the same size

Comment: You seem to have set a max width in each input as in `<input type="text" style="max-width:300px !important;" name="field1">`. Try and remove it and then take it from there

Comment: Yeah i did, i also tried adding it 500px and it doesn't increase the size, i even tried adding it in the css itself and it didn't work, i think there is something blocking it but i can't find what it is